# Runner на Unity, не получается вытащить значения из реестра в другую сцену

Tags: unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int score = 0;
    public static Score instance;
    public Text scoretext;
    private bool isdead = false;
    
    public DeathMenu menu;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
  

    private void Start()
    {
        instance = this;
        //ResetHigthscore();
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isdead)
            return;
        
    }
  
    public void OnisDead()
    {
        isdead = true;
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Higth score", score);//сохраняю значение в реестр
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        menu.TouchMenu(score);
    }
    public void IncreaseScore(int increment)
    {
        
        scoretext.text = ((int)score).ToString();
        score += increment;
    }
    
}


//скрипт другой сцены где загружаем значения из этого реестра

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoretext;
    public static MainMenu menu;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
   
    void Start()
    {
        scoretext.text = "Higth score: " + ((int)PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Higth score")).ToString();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    
    public void ToGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Level3");
    }
}

Использую Windows7. В реестре видно что данные сохраняются, но не загружаются в сцену
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы сохраняете через `SetFloat()`, а получаете через `GetInt()`, так работать не будет.
Или `SetFloat()` и `GetFloat()` или `SetInt()` и `GetInt()`

Comment: Совершенно верно. +1